# TypeError: cloudinaryStorage is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I'm trying to use Cloudinary in my code but for some reason, I'm getting TypeError.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
const app = express()

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
const { cloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary')

const router = express.Router()

const storage = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    folder: '',
    allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png']
})
```

It is the exact same code in npm multer-cloudinary-storage. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct code is the following. it's a big **C** and you missing the `new` word.

```
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: '',
        allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png']
    }

})
```

> It is the exact same code in npm multer-cloudinary-storage

No it's not.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary

Comment: it has solved it but now i have 'Cannot set property 'cloudinary' of undefined'

edit: solved it by adding 'new'

Comment: did you require cloudinary? Check out the examples in the npm repository and make sure you follow the examples **closely**